# Observations of a group with rank $52$ without Sylow theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm new to the group theory and want to get familar with the theorems in it, so I choose a number $52$ 
to try making some obseveration on all group that has this rank. Below are my thoughts. I don't know if there is any better way to think of these (i.e., an experienced group theorist would think), and I still have some questions not being solved. So I post this.

Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=52$. Since $52$ in not prime, then there is no theorem guarantee that $G$ must be cyclic. On the other hand, since $\Bbb Z_{52}$ is cyclic, so what we can know is only that "there exists a group $G$ with rank $52$ that is cyclic." Besides, $52$ is not of the form $pq$, where $p,~q$ are prime numbers, so again we can not use such theorem to say that $G$ must be cyclic. (Also, $52$ is not of the form $p^2$, so we're unable to conclude that $G$ is abelian anyway.)

So there remains a question: can $G$ be non-cyclic? I don't know how to answer it.

Next, move on to the obseverations on its subgroup. If $G$ is cyclic (i.e., isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{52}$), then by a theorem that I don't know its name, $G$ has *exactly* one nontrival proper subgroup of rank $2$ (also $4,~13,~26$, respectively). By Lagrange Theorem we know that these $4$ subgroup, plus the $\{e\}$ and $G$, are the all $6$ subgroups of $G$. However, since I don't know whether $G$ can be non-cyclic, so I discuss such case below. The prime divisors of $52$ are $2,~13$. By Cauchy theorem,  there exists at least one element that has order $2$ and $13$ respectively. So we know that there are two subgroups of $G$ with rank $2$ and $13$ respectively (but maybe $G$ has more subgroup with these ranks). However, how about subgroup with rank $26$ and $4$, etc.? Is their a way to tell whether such subgroup exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a direct product of cyclic groups of order $26$ and $2$ - this is abelian, but has no element of order $52$ so can't be cyclic.

Look out on your travels for a structure theorem on abelian groups which tells you  how to find all the different ones. If the prime factorisation of the order of $G$ is made up of distinct primes, the only possible abelian group is cyclic. If $G$ is divisible by the square (or higher power) of some prime, there will possible abelian groups which are not cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the Sylow theorems? They are the most commonly used tool to answer questions about groups of a given order. (For example, they will immediately tell you that a subgroup of order $4$ must exist.) Look up the Sylow theorems, and if you search "groups of order $x$" for many different values of $x$ you can find several discussions of this type (many on this site)>

Comment: Yes, I know there are Sylow theorems and they are useful to deal with such questions. However, I plan to study them in next 5 days, after I feel I have more acquaintance with the more basic group theorems. So I wonder if the tools I already have can solve such questions, to what extent. (I roughly feel/guess that the basic tools can conclude more facts in this case, but I can't figure it out.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the group $D_{26}$. That is, take a regular polygon with $26$ sides. Let $V_1,\ldots,V_{26}$ be its vertices (in order). Define these elements:

- $\tau$ is the rotation that maps each vertex to the next one. That is, $\tau(V_n)=V_{n+1}$ if $1\le n\le 25$ and $\tau(V_{26})=V_1$. The order of this element is $26$.
- $\rho$ is a symmetry with axis $V_1V_{14}$, and it has order two, like any other symmetry.

The group $\langle\tau,\rho\rangle$ is often called $D_{26}$, it has $52$ elements and $\rho\tau\neq\tau\rho$ (for example, $\tau\rho(V_1)=V_2$ and $\rho\tau(V_1)=V_{26}$), so this group is not abelian, and hence, is not cyclic either.

Comment: Thanks. A little question: if I don't know this concrete example (including Sylow theorem) before, is it possible to deduce that such non-cyclic group must exist?

Comment: Building the example is a way to deduce the existence. I don't know other.